# MATLAB fwrite\fread issue: two variables are being concatenated

Tags: matlab, file-io, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

I am reading in a binary EDF file and I have to split it into multiple smaller EDF files at specific points and then adjust some of the values inside. Overall it works quite well but when I read in the file it combines 2 character arrays with each other. Obviously everything afterwords gets corrupted as well. I am at a dead end and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The part of the code (writing) that has to contain the problem:

```
byt=fread(fid,8,'*char');
fwrite(tfid,byt,'*char');

fwrite(tfid,fread(fid,44));
%new number of records
s = records;
fwrite(tfid,s,'*char');
fseek(fid,8,0);
%test
fwrite(tfid,fread(fid,8,'*char'),'*char');
```

When I use the reader it combines the records (`fwrite(tfid,s,'*char')`)
with the value of the next variable. All variables before this are displayed correctly. The relevant code of the reader:

```
hdr.bytes      = str2double(fread(fid,8,'*char')');
reserved       = fread(fid,44);%#ok
hdr.records    = str2double(fread(fid,8,'*char')');
if hdr.records == -1
    beep
    disp('There appears to be a problem with this file; it returns an out-of-spec value of -1 for ''numberOfRecords.''')
    disp('Attempting to read the file with ''edfReadUntilDone'' instead....');
    [hdr, record] = edfreadUntilDone(fname, varargin);
    return
end
hdr.duration   = str2double(fread(fid,8,'*char')');
```

Comment: What is `s` in your writing code? A scalar or a vector?

Comment: its a char array
Its the number of recordings in the file saved as a string(char array)

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that your character array `s` does not have 8 characters in it, but you expect there to be 8 when you read it from the file. Whatever the number of characters in the array is, that's how many values [`fwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) will write out to the file. Anything less than 8 characters and you'll end up reading part of the next piece of data when you read from the file.

One fix would be to pad `s` with [blanks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blanks.html) before writing it:

```
s = [blanks(8-numel(records)) records];
```

In addition, the syntax `'*char'` is only valid when using [`fread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html): the `*` indicates that the output class should be `'char'` as well. It's unnecessary when using `fwrite`.